# IntelliJ, Maven y Spring para intentar generar un jar Runnable

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

Primero de todo muchas gracias por la ayuda. Os comento, estoy empezando a utilizar este entorno de programación, pero tengo problemas para generar el Jar y ejecutar mi programa fuera del entorno.  Os explico, el programa funciona cuando ejecuto la clase con el main de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Claro cuando intento generar el jar, no funciona. Creo que lo que falla es como estoy o ejecutando los comando de maven o como estoy configurando el Pom. Os enseño mi estructura de programa es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Os comento mi programa main esta en NoticiasApp y  estoy intentando compilarlo con Maven y la interfaz de IntelliJ.  Realizo el mvn install, packaje, etc y el jar resultante del proceso no funciona.

Aparte de eso, os adjunto un poco de información de mi pom.

```
 <build>
    <finalName>NoticiasApp</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>NoticiasApp</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>NoticiasApp</mainClass>
                        <name>NoticiasApp</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```